# Spanning a DIV over multiple rows

Tags: css, layout, html, positioning

I have a requirement to create a grid of tiles on a websites using DIVs. Some of the tiles can extend down and cover two rows and some tiles can extend to the right to cover two columns.

Assuming I find a way to properly place all these tiles, is this possible to do do this with straight-up CSS? We'd like to avoid using absolute positioning since the site should render correctly on multiple devices.

As a test, I came up with the following tile layout, and I can't think of a way to render it correctly.

```
+-------+---+
|       |   |
+---+---+   |
|   |   |   |
|   +---+---+
|   |       |
+---+-------+
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you done any CSS / HTML as of now?

Comment: Why do you need this design...how will it be used? It might be a good time to use a table. Or try experimenting with float positioning. You might be able to have a fluid outter DIV with the inner div sizes relative to the outter DIV...thereby, giving it some resize flexibility on devices.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stab at it:

```
<div style="background-color: #f00; width: 67%; float: left;"> foo</div>
<div style="background-color: #00f; width: 32%; float: right;"> foo<br />bar</div>
<div style="background-color: #0f0; width: 32%; float: left; "> foo <br /> bar</div>
<div style="background-color: #0ff; width: 32%; float: left; "> foo </div>
<div style="background-color: #ff0; width: 67%; float: right;"> foo </div>​
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9W2Nm/).

Answer (score 0):

#### Use something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="col2row1"></div>
    <div class="col1row2 right"></div>
    <div class="col1row2"></div>
    <div class="col2row1 right"></div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
div {border: 1px solid #999; float: left;}
.wrap {overflow: hidden; width: 160px; border: 0; float: none; margin: 100px;}
.col1row2 {width: 50px; height: 100px;}
.col2row1 {width: 100px; height: 50px;}
.right {float: right;}​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NBcEw/

#### Screenshot:

[image]

---

#### Instead of the hassles, there is another plugin:

[**jQuery Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is A dynamic layout plugin for jQuery, the flip-side of CSS floats.